# to copy the values from one dictionary to other dictionary in javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

The following code snippet is unable to copy the contents from one dictionary to other. It is throwing a type error showing "copy.Add is not a function". Can someone suggest the ways to copy the key-value pairs from one dictionary to other.

```
dict = {"Name":"xyz", "3": "39"};
var copy={};
console.log(dict);
for(var key in dict)
{
   copy.Add(key, dict[key]);
}
console.log(copy);
```

Comment: is this c# code?

Comment: @Sajeetharan is something wrong in it?

Answer (score 49):

In Javascript, use `Object.assign(copy, dict)` to copy contents into another already existing dictionary (i.e. "in-place" copy):

```
dict = {"Name":"xyz", "3": "39"};
var copy={};
console.log(dict, copy);
Object.assign(copy, dict);
console.log(dict, copy);
```

In newer JavaScript versions, you can also clone a dict into a new one using the `...` operator (this method creates a new instance):

```
var copy = {...dict};
```

Extra: You can also combine (merge) two dictionaries using this syntax. Either in-place:

```
Object.assign(copy, dict1, dict2);
```

or by creating a new instance:,

```
var copy = {...dict1, ...dict2};
```

Comment: all of these will not work for nested dicts. besides that, the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

You won´t need to call `add` on the `copy`-variable`. You can directly use the indexer as follows:

```
dict = {"Name":"xyz", "3": "39"};
var copy = {};
console.log(dict);
for(var key in dict)
{
    copy[key] = dict[key];
}
console.log(copy);
```

Comment: var copy = new Dictionary<string, string>(dict); oh, thats nice =D

Answer (score -3):

This should do it for you

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>() { {"Name", "xyz" }, {"3", "39"}};
            Dictionary<string, string> copy = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dic.Copy(copy);
            copy.ToList().ForEach(c => Console.Write("\n" + c));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public static class Ext
    {
        public static void Copy(this Dictionary<string, string> dic, Dictionary<string, string> other)
        {
            dic.ToList().ForEach(d => other.Add(d.Key, d.Value));
        } 
    }
}
```

Im sure this was answered before

Comment: I´d rather use a loop on the dictionary instead of `ToList.ForeEach` as the latter will produce a big memory-overhead from calling `ToList` which will put all values into memory followed by a second iteration of all those values.

Comment: Thanks for the advice/input there. Can that be a noticeable difference in all cases? If so whats any good reason to use the ToList and ForEach methods? Or is it just because I am chaining them together?

Comment: It´s just doing both which is doubling the memory-usage. If you allready *have* a list than everything is fine, however *creating* one for the sake of *iterating* it (which you can also using a normal `IEnumerable` and `foreach`) causes the doubling.